# fastest way to iterate a numpy array and update each element

Tags: python, numpy

This might be weird to you people, but I happen to have this weird goal to achieve, code goes as follows.

```
# A is a numpy array, dtype=int32,
# and each element is actually an ID(int), the ID range might be wide,
# but the actually existing values are quite fewer than the dense range,
A = array([[379621, 552965, 192509],
       [509849, 252786, 710979],
       [379621, 718598, 591201],
       [509849,  35700, 951719]])

# and I need to map these sparse ID to dense ones,
# my idea is to have a dict, mapping actual_sparse_ID -> dense_ID
M = {}

# so I iterate this numpy array, and check if this sparse ID has a dense one or not
for i in np.nditer(A, op_flags=['readwrite']):
    if i not in M:
        M[i] = len(M)  # sparse ID got a dense one
    i[...] = M[i]   # replace sparse one with the dense ID
```

My goal could be achieved with `np.unique(A, return_inverse=True)`, and the `return_inverse` result is what I want.

However, the numpy array I have is too huge to fully load into memory, so I cannot run np.unique over the whole data, and this is why I came up with this dict-mapping idea...

Is this the right way to go? Any possible improvement?

Comment: Can you provide sample output?

Comment: Anyway, sounds like `np.unique` is what you need.

Comment: @YakymPirozhenko, you're so right about it, `np.unique` could `return_inverse`, and that's what I need, however, the numpy array I have is too huge to fully load into memory, so I cannot run `np.unique` over the whole data, and this is why I came up with this dict-mapping idea...

Comment: @PM2Ring, updated

Comment: To be more specific, this code would work if you had sufficient RAM: `_, indices = np.unique(A, return_inverse=True); indices = indices.reshape(A.shape)`

Comment: Your own algorithm does not work: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'`

Comment: Also, it is not clear how _your_ algorithm provides any benefits over `np.unique()` - it seems that you still have to load the entire array `A` into memory regardless of used algorithm.

Comment: @AGNGazer, no, I could load the huge data into `A` chunk by chunk,

Comment: @PM2Ring, yes, but sufficient RAM is not guaranteed.

Comment: Understood. The code in that comment is just to illustrate the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

I will make an attempt to provide an alternative way of doing this by using `numpy.unique()` on sub-arrays. This solution is not fully tested. I also did not do any side-by-side performance evaluation since your solution is not fully working for me.

Let's say we have an array `c` that we split into two smaller arrays. Let's create some test data, for example:

```
>>> a = np.array([[1,1,2,3,4],[1,2,6,6,2],[8,0,1,1,4]])
>>> b = np.array([[11,2,-1,12,6],[12,2,6,11,2],[7,0,3,1,3]])
>>> c = np.vstack([a, b])
>>> print(c)
[[ 1  1  2  3  4]
 [ 1  2  6  6  2]
 [ 8  0  1  1  4]
 [11  2 -1 12  6]
 [12  2  6 11  2]
 [ 7  0  3  1  3]]
```

Here we assume that `c` is the large array and `a` and `b` are sub-arrays. Of course, one could build `c` first and then *extract* sub-arrays.

Next step is to run `numpy.unique()` on the two sub-arrays:

```
>>> ua, ia = np.unique(a, return_inverse=True)
>>> ub, ib = np.unique(b, return_inverse=True)
>>> uc, ic = np.unique(c, return_inverse=True) # this is for future reference
```

Now, here is an algorithm for combining the results from subarrays:

```
def merge_unique(ua, ia, ub, ib):
    # make copies *if* changing inputs is undesirable:
    ua = ua.copy()
    ia = ia.copy()
    ub = ub.copy()
    ib = ib.copy()

    # find differences between unique values in the two arrays:
    diffab = np.setdiff1d(ua, ub, assume_unique=True)
    diffba = np.setdiff1d(ub, ua, assume_unique=True)

    # find indices in ua, ub where to insert "other" unique values:
    ssa = np.searchsorted(ua, diffba)
    ssb = np.searchsorted(ub, diffab)

    # throw away values that are too large:
    ssa = ssa[np.where(ssa < len(ua))]
    ssb = ssb[np.where(ssb < len(ub))]

    # increment indices past previously computed "insert" positions:
    for v in ssa[::-1]:
        ia[ia >= v] += 1
    for v in ssb[::-1]:
        ib[ib >= v] += 1

    # combine results:
    uc = np.union1d(ua, ub) # or use ssa, ssb, diffba, diffab to update ua, ub
    ic = np.concatenate([ia, ib])
    return uc, ic
```

Now, let's run this function on the results of `numpy.unique()` from sub-arrays and then compare merged indices and unique values with the reference results `uc` and `ic`:

```
>>> uc2, ic2 = merge_unique(ua, ia, ub, ib)
>>> np.all(uc2 == uc)
True
>>> np.all(ic2 == ic)
True
```

Splitting into more than two sub-arrays can be handled with little additional work - simply keep accumulating "unique" values and indices, like this:

```
uacc, iacc = np.unique(subarr1, return_inverse=True)
ui, ii = np.unique(subarr2, return_inverse=True)
uacc, iacc = merge_unique(uacc, iacc, ui, ii)
ui, ii = np.unique(subarr3, return_inverse=True)
uacc, iacc = merge_unique(uacc, iacc, ui, ii)
ui, ii = np.unique(subarr4, return_inverse=True)
uacc, iacc = merge_unique(uacc, iacc, ui, ii)
................................ (etc.)
```